# Re-sending an errored out triggered email

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, error, triggered-send, queue

Recently one of my trigger's `data extensions` was updated, and this in turn broke my `ampscript` within the template associated to the trigger.

This caused calls to the trigger associated to queue the send requests. I was late in **finding this error and had built up 14,000 or so queued send requests that no longer worked with the ampscript**.

I've fixed the `ampscript` and the `trigger` is now sending as it should,

**but out of those 14,000 trigger send requests 12,000 of them timed out and never got sent.**

***Is there a way to re-queue those triggered send requests and have them try to send again?***

The error was with a `timestamp` field that gets auto populated, so the data within the 12,000 error requests will work.

Any info would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to run the not sent tracking extract for the job where the subscribers went to error.

1. Run the Not sent extract
2. import the CSV into a DE
3. Write a Query to join your new DE and the Triggeredsend DE to pull info personalization info.
4. Do a batch send to the target DE from step 3